# Unable to make HTTP connection to nginx running on Raspberry Pi from desktop

Tags: raspbian, networking, web-server, wifi

I am trying to set up my first web server using the Raspberry Pi. I have installed nginx and when I go to the IP address of my Pi, I can see `Welcome to NGINX on Debian` displayed but if I go to the same exact IP address from my desktop, I cannot connect. I cannot ping the IP address either from my desktop. Both time out. I also cannot port forward because the IP address is not identifiable in the WLAN. The IP address I'm trying to reach is from the `wlan0` section from running the `ifconfig` command. What am I doing wrong? I have network discovery on for my PC and both machines are connected to the same network. Thanks!

EDIT: desktop IP is 192.168.1.58 and Pi IP is 192.168.1.137 so it seems both are on local network

I am trying but I don't know how to debug. I looked at some posts like the ones below but none were helpful.

[difficulties-accessing-my-raspberry-pi-nginx-web-server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/difficulties-accessing-my-raspberry-pi-nginx-web-server)

[how-to-configure-a-web-server-that-can-display-data-from-my-raspberry-pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19690/how-to-configure-a-web-server-that-can-display-data-from-my-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Are both the desktop and the Pi on the same subnet ?   Also, routers often have a setting that isolates wifi clients from LAN clients...

Comment: Further to KennetRunner's suggestion above, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the local IP addresses of both the Pi and the desktop. If you can't ping the Pi from the desktop I would forget about nginx problems for the time being - the issue isn't there, it's something related to your network setup.

Comment: I am connected to the Wifi for both the PC and the Pi. The desktop's IP is 192.168.1.58 and the Pi's IP is 192.168.1.137 so it seems both are on the local network. @goobering

Comment: Could it be that the desktop is using IPv4 and the pi is using IPv6? Is inet address in IPv6?